# Should we mark identification requests that turn out to look for the same thing as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, identification-questions

Suppose that question X and question Y are both [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) questions, and suppose that it turns out that in both cases, the thing to be identified was anime Z. Should question X be marked as a duplicate of Y (or vice versa)?

For example, the question https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/9949/a-comedy-manga-about-a-guy-who-protects-his-house-from-a-girl-that-comes-from-th was marked as a duplicate of the earlier question https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4405/comedy-manga-with-a-16-year-old-boy-from-a-poor-family; both questions were looking for the manga *Sakuratetsu Taiwahen*. In this case, the answers were the same, but the questions were different.

Contrast this with the question https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6721/who-is-this-character, which was closed as a duplicate of [What anime is this winking girl from?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4282/what-anime-is-this-winking-girl-from) - in this case, the questions themselves were obviously the same, so I think we all agree that this closure-as-duplicate was correct and appropriate. This is not the type of situation I am talking about in this question.

Relevant discussions elsewhere:

- [Why would VTC as duplicate be appropriate for a story identification question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3431/why-would-vtc-as-duplicate-be-appropriate-for-a-story-identification-question) at meta.scifi
- [Should story-identification requests that turn out to be about the same story be marked as duplicate?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3375/should-story-identification-requests-that-turn-out-to-be-about-the-same-story-be) at meta.scifi

Comment: I've been wondering about this too, but the one who can confirm duplicate is OP, others can only tell that this might be the same but never be sure about it. Unless it's obvious id request. Maybe we can mark as duplicate as soon as he accept the answer

Comment: what is 'mark-as-duplicate' do actually? I always thought that this is the way community says "here's an answer and question, you're not searching it good enough" if this is the case then this shouldn't be mark as duplicate since it's impossible to search this kind of id request here.

Comment: @ShinobuOshino That's basically the idea - "here is a place where your question has already been answered". The problem is that marking id-requests as duplicates can't really be helpful - we only can be sure it's a duplicate _after_ OP has already accepted an answer or posted a comment saying "this is what I was looking for" or something.

Comment: I've wondered about this too, but yeah, the first question doesn't accept any answer, thus no way to know if it's duplicate or not. I agree with the view in the first link though. Duplicate notice says "This question has been asked before", yet they give totally different description, and "already has an answer", yet, in this one, the first one has accepted no answer yet. Well, actually, I just feel marking the second as duplicate ain't fair...

Comment: I don't particularly see a benefit to doing this. For ordinary questions, the reason for closing duplicates is so that the answers will all be in one place. For ID requests, before answers are accepted by the OP, there's no way to tell if they're duplicates. After they're accepted, more answers are universally either redundant or incorrect unless they contain extra information that is especially specific to the description. Hence, ID requests shouldn't be getting more late answers anyway. If others want to do this, go ahead, but I don't see it as worth our time.

Answer (score 4):

> Here's my take on this, it doesn't represent some community consensus but my own personal opinion.

Yes.

There are two cases of closing as a duplicate:

1. The question was **exactly** asked before, generally posted again by the same author.
2. The question is **answered** elsewhere on the site.

Identification questions with anime already identified match the second rule, so I argue that they should be closed as duplicates.

It can be preferable to add details not found on the original question from the asked duplicate back to the original, to make the question more complete.